# If most Puranas are a conversation between Shaunaka and Sauti, how is that we see variations in creation and other stories?

Tags: puranas, vyasa

As we know, there are 18 Puranas, and many more Upa Puranas.
Nearly all of them begin in the same way, namely: Sarga and Visarga - Creation and Secondary Creation.

And most Puranas begin with Shaunaka asking Ugrashrava Sauti, "Please describe to us the glories of [insert name(s) here]."

Now if most Puranas are a conversation between Shaunaka and Sauti, how come there are variations in the same creation stories and other stories in each Purana? Like wouldn't the Rishis listening to them say, "Hey! Yesterday you said this happened, today you are saying something else happened!"

How are these variations justified?

Also, I've a secondary question:

I understand that how much ever we describe the glories of the Lord, they always sound fresh, but just because of that wouldn't the assembled Rishis get bored of listening again to the same story of creation?

Comment: I think you answered your own question when you said "I understand that how much ever we describe the glories of the Lord, they always sound fresh."  As far as apparent contradictions between Puranas go, in many cases that's due to interpolations in one or both of the texts, so when the sages heard it they wouldn't have heard contradictory versions.  And then of course there's the notion of Sattvic Puranas, Rajasic Puranas, etc. in the case of core difference about whether Vishnu or Shiva came first.

Comment: By the way, there are places in the Puranas where the sages say to Ugrashrava "We know this story, but we want you to tell it to us."  And there are places where they say things like, "You told us that Daksha came from Brahma's ear, but we have heard previously that he came from Brahma's thumb."  And then Ugrashrava clarifies that there were two Dakshas, etc.

Comment: @Keshav That Darsham story occurs twice in Srimad Bhagavatam itself. And while Krsna's glories are eternal I don't think that Brahma sitting on his lotus and creating can be counted as His glory.

Comment: Well, I think the glories of all the gods always sound fresh, not just Vishnu's.

Comment: @Keshav Huh. Guess I'll have to edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I think in some case it is more of a way of starting stories and not the real sages asking the other sages/Gods. For some cases it might be true but in other cases, seems same style of writing was copied.

Comment: @Surya I think you should add specific examples to make it little clearer. I've made some edits so it can be re-opened but I think it needs some concrete examples, right now it look vague. So I actually closed it as 'too-broad' instead of 'opinion-based'.

Comment: @Surya i think you know Kalpa Bheda but i guess your answer is not Kalpa Bheda.

Comment: @sv. Thanks for the title change. I shall see what examples can be added.

Comment: @TheDestroyer There is one example i can think for which Kalpa Bheda may not be the answer - Jalandhara and Shankhachuda.